# How to add indent after formula?

Tags: spacing

I have stuation like this:
[image]

I need indent after formulas (where question mark is). How to do that?

**UPDATE**

Code, used in here

```
\textbf{Определение 1\cite{1}.} \textit{Непрерывная на всей вещественной оси 
функция $f(x)$ называется равномерной почти--периодической, если для каждого 
$\varepsilon>0$ можно указать такое положительное число $l=l(\varepsilon)$, 
что в каждом интервале длины $l$ найдется хотя бы одно число $\tau$, для 
которого выполняется неравенство}
\[
|f(x+\tau)-f(x)|<\varepsilon(-\infty<x<\infty).
\]
Пространство равномерных почти--периодических функций, его обозначим через  $\mathbf{B}$, есть замыкание множества тригонометрических полиномов
```

Comment: Since an indent is used to signify a new paragraph, you merely need to leave a blank line in your tex file after the formula to cause a new paragraph.  That said, new paragraphs following a formula are often frowned upon.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes but it makes empty space after formula. How can I fix it?

Comment: That is why it is frowned upon :^)

Comment: Instead of the blank line, you can add `\hspace{\parindent}` after the formula.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- Ordinarily, `\hspace` disappears at the beginning of a line.  `\hspace*` would be preserved there.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of code that produces the output you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the extra space that comes with an actual `\par`, you can issue a `\hspace*{\parindent}` following the formula.

As had been my original comment to the OP, David also suggests using an actual blank line (`\par`) after the formula to actually force a new paragraph.  However, for those using `\parskip`, this will cause additional vertical space to be inserted.  Since the OP replied to that comment, making reference to undesirable "empty space" being inserted, this perhaps applies to the OP's particular case.

The MWE shows the *unusual* case where both `\parskip` and `\parindent` are active.  I have set `\parskip` unusually large to amplify the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\parskip 4ex\relax% TO EXAGGERATE
\newcommand\fauxpar{\hspace*{\parindent}}
\begin{document}
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
\[y = x\]
\fauxpar Faux Par 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
\[y = x\]

Normal Par
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use a real paragraph  with a blank line. (It doesn't add vertical space)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ...unless `\parskip` is active.

Comment: but it isn't here. and if it was then \parindent should be 0pt anyway, as having non zero parindent and parskip is somewhat unusual.